# Explicit Assignment of 2 Variables To A Multi-Value Return Function

Tags: variables, go, variable-declaration

So, given the function `xml.MarshalIndent(xmlLiteralFromStruct, "", "  ")`, which returns a `[]byte` and an `error`, you could assign 2 variables to the two return values with shorthand syntax like so: 
`xmlEncodedMsg, err := xml.MarshalIndent(xmlLiteralFromStruct, "", "  ")`

My question is (and I know this code doesn't work, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do) is there a way to explicitly declare both variables and their types similar to this: 
`var xmlEncodedMsg, err ([]byte, error) = xml.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "  ")`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: No, not if the types are different and you also want the assignment on the same line. Without the assignment you could use `;` to declare multiple variables of different types on one line but I belive gofmt might format it into multiple lines. [This](https://play.golang.org/p/AJsjLdipu7Y) is the most you can do but i would not recommend it. Use `:=` wherever possible.

Comment: Are you asking because you want to do this outside of a function? If so, then no, there's no way to do that in a single statement (you'd have to do it with some initialization code somewhere). If it's inside a function, just use `:=`.

Comment: @mkopriva That was a very well formulated answer. Thanks that helps. Sorry for being so nitty griitty.

Comment: @AndySchweig I understand that now. I've seen examples like what you are describing. Now that I think of it any, that's a really verbose line of code I came up with up there anyway. I'll just use type inference.